# How can properly render content that contain new line using JS?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, laravel

I have a string look like this that I query from the database.

In the controller, I ran

```
dd($disclaimer);
```

I get

```
"""
q\n
a
"""
```

Then, I'm trying to access it the JS like this

```
$scope.disclaimer.text = '{!! $disclaimer or '' !!}';
```

I also try

```
$scope.disclaimer.text = JSON.parse('{!! $disclaimer or '' !!}');
```

I kept getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

How would one go about debugging this?

Comment: what is the value on $disclaimer? json, array, string, object etc

Comment: what is the value or what is the type ?

Comment: `dd(gettype($disclaimer)); //"string"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick for me, just in case anyone ran into the same issue.

```
$scope.disclaimer.text = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({!! json_encode($disclaimer) !!}));
```